# it displays Name Error name MEETING_TIMES is not defined

Tags: python, oop, object, methods, nameerror

i have defined a 2D array of MEETING_TIMES But it shows me NameError also it shows error
about data object of class Data

```
class Data:
    MEETING_TIMES = [
        ["MT1", "MWF 09:30 - 12:00"],
        ["MT2", "MWF 01:30 - 04:00"],
        ["MT3", "TTH 09:30 - 12:00"],
        ["MT4", "TTH 01:30 - 04:00"]
    ]

    def __init__(self): 
        self._meetingTimes = []
        for i in range(0, len(MEETING_TIMES)):
            self._meetingTimes.append(MeetingTime(self.MEETING_TIMES[i][0],
            self.MEETING_TIMES[i][1]))
            # Parameters = id and meeting time

data = Data()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe you're confusing class variables and instance variables. The way you've defined `MEETING_TIMES`, it's a class variable. It is a property of the entire class Data, and not just any particular instance of it. So, to refer to it, you use Data.MEETING_TIME, since it's a property of the actual class.

You might want to try code more along the lines of:

```
class Data:
    MEETING_TIMES = [
    ["MT1", "MWF 09:30 - 12:00"],
    ["MT2", "MWF 01:30 - 04:00"],
    ["MT3", "TTH 09:30 - 12:00"],
    ["MT4", "TTH 01:30 - 04:00"]
    ]
    def __init__(self): 
        self._meetingTimes = []
        for i in range(0, len(Data.MEETING_TIMES)):
            self._meetingTimes.append(????(Data.MEETING_TIMES[i][0],
            Data.MEETING_TIMES[i][1]))
            # Parameters = id and meeting time
data = Data()
```

where, I'm afraid I substituted `???` for `MeetingTime`, since I wasn't certain what method that spelling referred to.

Comment: Its okay to reference a class variable by `self.MEETING_TIMES` - in fact that's the preferred way so that an child class or instance can change it.

Comment: ThankYou @tdelaney that's the error you pointed! now it's working.

Comment: @ZainSadaqat  - you should reference the variable as `self.MEETING_TIMES` not `Data.MEETING_TIMES` as suggested here. Doing so means that a subclass can modify `MEETING_TIMES` and still have the parent class methods work.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you correctly use `self.MEETING_TIMES` and others you incorrectly use `MEETING_TIMES`. So, what's the difference? When executing a method, a variable can be local to the method, global to the module its defined in or in the "super global" builtins namespace. In the first case, `self` is in the local namespace (so far so good) but `MEETING_TIMES` is not. There is a further rule for instance objects: if a variable is not in the instance data, python looks at the class namespace. Python sees `self`, but doesn't see `self.MEETING_TIMES` so falls back to `self.__class__.MEETING_TIMES` where the variable is defined.